# Screen and World space UI in the same scene

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have a Unity project, where I need to have both - screen space and world space UI elements (It's an AR project so I need to have some buttons in the world space, and others - attached to the screen).

As I understand I shouldn't have more than  UI canvas in the scene, so how can I have both Screen and World space UI elements in the same scene?

Comment: *`As I understand I shouldn't have more than UI canvas in the scene`* This is false. I believe [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wxitgdx-UI) goes over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have more than one canvas in Unity scene, just right click on the hierarchy an add 2 canvas, make one world space and other screen space. [check the official tutorial here](https://youtu.be/OD-p1eMsyrU)